# How to inject a dependency into a Processor

Tags: dependency-injection, processor

My processor is defined as follows:

```
<processor type="MyProject.MyProcessor, MyProject" resolve="true" />
```

I have then defined my Configurator Class:

```
<sitecore>
    <services>
        <configurator type="MyProject.MyConfiguratorClass, MyProject" />
    </services>
</sitecore>
```

And inside `MyConfiguratorClass` I will do something like

```
public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) {
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<classType>(somethingElse);
}
```

**Question**

The Processor that I want to inject to implements an `Abstract` class with a Constructor that is already defined and has its own parameters. How can I inject another dependency - say, an instance of the class `MyProject.InjectedClass` in it?

Comment: An abstract class (with constructor) could never be instantiated. The inheriting class would need to implement it's own constructor and call base(base args). The inheriting constructor should ask for the dependency.

Comment: Yes, of course the `MyProject.MyProcessor` class implements that constructor.
I'm still unsure how should I perform the `serviceCollection.AddSingleton()` call in order to allow `MyProject.MyProcessor` to access an instance of injected class.

Comment: It would just ask for it....   ? :D   By that I mean in it's constructor.

Comment: There is clearly something that I am missing. If the Constructor in the Abstract class has already 3 parameters, and I cannot change the signature when implementing the Constructor, how can I sneak in a 4th parameter with my injected class?

Comment: public MyInheitedClass(IString a1, string a2, string a3, string a4) : base(a2, a3, a4)

Comment: This works for me. If you put it as an answer, I'll be glad to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not shared the actual classes in question, so I have to extrapolate.

But if you have

```
public abstract ClassA
{
    public ClassA(IDependency dependencyOne)
    {
         ...
    }
}

public ClassB : ClassA
{
    public ClassB(IDependency dependencyOne, string connectionStringName) : base(dependencyone)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then this would be one example of how it can be done. Since the abstract class does not have a parameterless constructor, your constructor HAS to derive `base` on all of its constructors.

If you're not using interfaces but instead the abstract type, none of this really changes. You can do:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ClassA>(ClassB);
```

Assuming there is another mapping in place for `IDependency`.

Answer (score -1):

If the inherited class constructor has more parameters than its base class constructor we can use the below syntax.

```
public inheritedClass(param p1, param p2, param p3):base(p1, p2){}
```

Thanks,
Akif